# Como fazer botão para confirmar se deseja sair da página?

Tags: javascript

Como fazer com que meu botão `voltar` informe ao usuário se ele deseja realmente sair da página e depois direcionar para o `index.html` usando JavaScript? Não é bem um botão, estou usando `href` para redirecionar ao `index` enquanto isso. Quero saber se é correto fazer isso mesmo.

```
<div class="groupb">
   <a href="index.html" class="botoes">voltar</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples, use o evento *OnBeforeUnload* ou *beforeunload* ele é chamado antes da janela ser fechada. Veja os exemplos:

### OnBeforeUnload

```js
function confirmaSaida() {
    return 'Você deseja realmente sair da página?';
}

window.onbeforeunload = confirmaSaida;
```

```html
<a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com">SOpt</a>
```

### beforeunload

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
  event.returnValue = "Você deseja realmente sair da página?";
});
```

```html
<a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com">SOpt</a>
```

### Referência

- [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) em Inglês
- [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) em Português

Comment: Legal cara! To recebendo até confirmação para sair desta página depois de executar seu snippet.

Comment: @DvD eita eu não tinha reparado nisso **:)**

Comment: Ate´ pra desligar o computador rs